# Add time zone to date picker

Tags: ios, swift, datepicker

How would I add a time zone to the date picker?
This is the code I have right now: with the output format : like this  2018-04-10T04:24:24.443980+08:00

```
@available(iOS 11.0, *)
    func donePressed() {
        let formatter = ISO8601DateFormatter()
        if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
            formatter.formatOptions.insert(.withFractionalSeconds)
        } else {
            // Fallback on earlier versions
        }
        let dateString = formatter.string(from: picker.date)
        choreSchedule.text =  "\(dateString)"
    }
```

Comment: Your question is not clear. What change do you actually want? And why are you showing the user a date in an ISO8601 format? Why not show the date in a proper human readable format appropriate for the user's locale?

Comment: The question is not clear @durn can you explain more.?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're just trying to set the time zone from the user's system, you can use the TimeZone.current property when you set up the UIDatePicker (or pick the time zone of your choosing):

```
let picker = UIDatePicker()
picker.timeZone = .current
```

or if you had a variable time zone:

```
func donePressed(timeZone: TimeZone) {
    let formatter = ISO8601DateFormatter()
    if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
        formatter.formatOptions.insert(.withFractionalSeconds)
    } else {
        // Fallback on earlier versions
    }
    picker.timeZone = timeZone
    let dateString = formatter.string(from: picker.date)
    choreSchedule.text =  "\(dateString)"
}
```

Comment: can you integrate that idea to my code above so i can upvote

Comment: It wouldn't typically be in the above code so integrating didn't make sense.  You _could_ put it right above the formatter.string(from: picker.date) line but I'd never recommend doing that because you'd be setting it every time the picker was used (instead of just once).   Normally, you'd set it when you create the date picker (e.g. right after let picker = UIDatePicker()) or in the viewDidLoad() of your view controller.   I'll tweak the above for this latter scenario though if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

`picker.timeZone = .current` doesn't work for me

`formatter.timeZone = .current` does.

For the given question:

```
func donePressed() {
    let formatter = ISO8601DateFormatter()
    formatter.timeZone = .current
    if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
        formatter.formatOptions.insert(.withFractionalSeconds)
    } else {
        // Fallback on earlier versions
    }
    let dateString = formatter.string(from: picker.date)
    choreSchedule.text =  "\(dateString)"
}
```

Also, for setting some other timezone, you may replace `formatter.timeZone = .current` with `formatter.timeZone = TimeZone(identifier: "EST")`

the identifier "EST" is an abbreviation to a specific timezone. For the list of timezones available, you can try:

`print(TimeZone.abbreviationDictionary)`